# Platform Agnostic Way to Tell if Meteor is Running

Tags: meteor

Question says it all really.  I can setup a page at a known location, and make sure the http request works, but that feels kinda hackey.

Comment: Do you mean like [Meteor.status](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_status) from within your app, or via an external site like WebPulse?

Answer (score 1):

`Meteor.status()` is a client side function which will help for *individual* clients within the Meteor context. Your best bet for a platform-agnostic check is a [DDP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128430/documentation-or-code-details-on-meteors-ddp-pub-sub-protocol) that lives **outside** your Meteor environment. (True, the Meteor folks proposed the DDP client, but the intention is that it serve as a [protocol for real-time platform](http://2012.realtimeconf.com/video/matt-debergalis), not a tightly coupled part of the Meteor architecture).

In practice, then, you'd need to wire up a DDP client and subscribe to a server-side publication, returning whatever defines 'running' in the context you require. This could be simply a collection of mongo documents, or some status checks based on more complex `set` and `unset` [method calls](http://docs.meteor.com/#publish_set) within your publish function.

Here are a couple DDP clients I've found

- [DDPClient.NET](https://github.com/sonyarouje/DDPClient.NET)
- [node-ddp-client](https://github.com/oortcloud/node-ddp-client)
- [ruby-ddp-client](https://github.com/tmeasday/ruby-ddp-client)

Hope that helps.